# Get part of string before and after character only if the character exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the following code to get the string before and after the pipe character |
The data looks like this:

```
AMOUNT
1000
28373|7000
72727
82773|1090
5000
```

However, if the character doesnt exist, the result is blank. So, the values 1000, 72727 and 5000 would not be picked up.

How can I pick up the left and right strings if they exist but also pick up the string if the | character is not there?

Any assistance here would be appreciated

```
SUBSTRING(AMOUNT,0, CHARINDEX('|',AMOUNT)) AS AMOUNT1
SUBSTRING(AMOUNT, CHARINDEX('|', AMOUNT) + 1, LEN(AMOUNT)) AS AMOUNT2
```

Comment: SQLite or SQL Server? Those are two very different database products

Answer (score 0):

You can add the character so this works:

```
LEFT(AMOUNT, CHARINDEX('|', AMOUNT + '|')) AS AMOUNT1,
SUBSTRING(AMOUNT, CHARINDEX('|', AMOUNT + '|') + 1, LEN(AMOUNT)) AS AMOUNT2
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ea6d4211c19a95a7f4984eb05e68fa50) is a db<>fiddle.